# C# Get one XML element value when another is a specific value

Tags: c#, xml

Is there a possible way within C# to get the value of the `<PropertyID>` node only when `<IsDisabled>` is equal to 0?

If not, how would I be able to parse out the PropertyIDs that have an IsDisabled value of 0?

I've been beating myself up with this all day so any help would be appreciated.

I have attached an example snippet of my XML below. I have condensed it significantly and there are many with a value of 1 and many with 0.

```
<response>
  <code>200</code>
  <result>
    <PhysicalProperty>
      <Property>
        <PropertyID>325213</PropertyID>
        <MarketingName>XXXXX</MarketingName>
        <Type>Student</Type>
        <IsDisabled>1</IsDisabled>
        <IsFeaturedProperty>0</IsFeaturedProperty>
      </Property>
    </PhysicalProperty>
  </result>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, LINQ makes it pretty easy to do these types of queries against XML

```
var propertyIds = XDocument.Parse(myXmlString)
                           .Descendants("Property")
                           .Where(p => p.Element("IsDisabled").Value == "0")
                           .Select(p => p.Element("PropertyID").Value);
```

Comment: Ok. I kind of get it. In this context what does p mean in your code?

Comment: `=>` denotes an anonymous method.  The left side (the `p`) are the arguments going into the method, the right side is the method body.  You can research `anonymous method` or `lambda`